# How to deal with this error in nested lists?

Tags: r, list, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have this R code below to fill in nested lists:

```
    my_information = list()
    for(a in 1:(length(first_list))){
    my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]]=a
      for(b in 1:(length(second_list))){
        my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]] = second_list[[b]] - first_list[[a]]
       if(my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]]>0){

        for(c in 1:length(third_list)){
          my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]][[paste0("third_list",c)]] = third_list[[c]] - second_list[[b]])
         
          for(d in 1:length(fourth_list)){
           
            my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]][[paste0("third_list",c)]][[paste0("fourth_list",d)]] = fourth_list[[d]] - third_list[c])
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

When I run this code, I  get the error:

```
Error in my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]]<- `*vtmp*`
 more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

I'm not sure how to solve this inside the nested loops, any idea is appreciated

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

I got it to function, though without data and an expected output I'm not sure if it "works".  The main problem was (I think) that you intended each element of each list to itself be a list.  The way the code was written, you hadn't defined those elements as lists already, they were just vectors.  The code below defines each element of each list as a list inside the loop and then populates it.

```
first_list <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
second_list <- list(d=4, e=5, f=6)
third_list <- list(g=7, h=8, i=9)
fourth_list <- list(j=10, k=11, l=12)

my_information = list()
for(a in 1:(length(first_list))){
  my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]] <- a
  for(b in 1:(length(second_list))){
    my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]] <- list()
    my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]] <- second_list[[b]] - first_list[[a]]
    if(my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]]>0){
      for(c in 1:length(third_list)){
        my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]] <- list()
        my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]][[paste0("third_list",c)]] = third_list[[c]] - second_list[[b]]
        for(d in 1:length(fourth_list)){
          my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]][[paste0("third_list",c)]] <- list()
          my_information[[paste0("first_list",a)]][[paste0("second_list",b)]][[paste0("third_list",c)]][[paste0("fourth_list",d)]] = fourth_list[[d]] - third_list[[c]]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```